# HP B120i Raid showing two disk in CentOS7

Tags: linux, fakeraid

We have HP DL360e G8 with `B120i` RAID controller (which is FakeRAID) and i have configured `RAID 1` in RAID configuration utility. After CentOS 7 installation when i run `fdisk -l` i am seeing two individual disk with same partition size.

I should suppose to see single disk (/dev/sda) right?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00020b93

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      526335      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          526336     8914943     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         8914944   976707583   483896320   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00020b93

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      526335      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          526336     8914943     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3         8914944   976707583   483896320   8e  Linux LVM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption of seeing a single drive is correct.

That said, I have my own bad experience with FakeRAID (BIOS-assisted RAID).

It just does not work well with most of Linux distributions.

My recommendation is to:

1. Disable FakeRAID in BIOS
2. Install `mdadm`
3. Set up a very manageable and reliable software RAID

---

I sadly don't know, why you are seeing two drives instead of one.

---

Performance-wise `mdadm` is the same CPU workload. There is absolutely no difference, guaranteed.

---

For information about Bootable RAID using `mdadm`, please [refer to one of the articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdadm%20bootable%20raid%201&oq=mdadm%20boot) that suites you best.

Comment: But i have few more server running `B320i RAID Controller` and they seems working fine and showing single drive in CentOS 7.3. so why B120i having issue?

Comment: I totally agreed with you, I am only worried about performance between `B120i` Vs `mdadm`

Comment: Does `mdadm` provide boot level protection? just trying to find what is the difference between `rakeRAID` and OS Raid?

Comment: @Satish You want to use this RAID as a boot drive? That is a little complicated.

Comment: I want full redendency not just single file system protection, i want my OS up and running 99.999 uptime.

Comment: I understand, in my case we have no data all we have CPU crunching and availability of OS, can't we RAID /boot partition?

Comment: In my question if i am seeing two disk in `fdisk -l` that mean my `B120i` RAID is broken right?

Comment: @Satish I believe so. But since I am no longer working with FakeRAID for years, can't be sure. But the probability is high enough.

Comment: no worry! Thanks and thus i accepted your answer

Comment: @Satish You are welcome, friend.

Comment: @Satish, there are plenty of how-tos on the internet explaining how to setup a redundant `/boot` partition with `mdadm`. The only difference here is that you will map `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/md0` and the caveat here is that you will have to install grub on both partitions (  `(hd0,0)` and `(hd1,0)` on grub sintax to -> `sda1` , `sdb1` )  to have a redundant bootloader, but the grub config file will point to `/dev/md0` as boot partition ( `set root='(md/0)'` ) - https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-debian-squeeze-p2